# split rows in dataframe into multiple rows in a column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with 10 columns and 15 rows.

[image]

If I have an empty dataframe df2 with only two columns (A,B), If I want to copy all values in row0 in split it in multiple rows in column (A). The same is for row 2 in column(B). Row 3 in column(A) and so on. I tried many functions, but I couldn't achieve this. Any suggestion?

Comment: please attach the expected output

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just to transpose the dataframe (first two rows):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate original (test) dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({f'col_{i+1}': np.random.randint(0, 100, 20) for i in range(10)})

# transpose the first two rows into a new dataframe
df1 = df.iloc[:2, :].T.reset_index(drop=True)

# rename columns as needed
df1.rename(columns={0: 'A', 1: 'B'}, inplace=True)
```